# How to switch back to a (file) buffer no longer visible, in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I opened a file in Emacs using <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd>. The file replaces the buffer in which an old file was residing. Now I want to go back to the old file without giving the actual path to open it. Is there any command for this?

Comment: Try `C-x b`. It calls `switch-to-buffer`

Comment: @saidesh why should the question be in code-formatting?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like "buffer" and "window" are being confused.  Also, check out http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles.

Answer (score 1):

File opening does not replace buffers. It opens new buffers, so the old buffer is already there. Try the command `M-x list-buffers` (`C-x C-b`) to see the open buffers.

Also see this: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html

And this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers

Answer (score 0):

I use `session.el` and `minibuf-isearch.el`. If you use them, you can search the history of file you opened with `C-x C-f` by `C-x C-f C-r what-file-you-want RET RET` even if you closed and restart Emacs. It's incredibly useful.